# Can I copy a Boost::Log sink and change it?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm currently creating a log sink that dumps log lines from the output of my `Trainer` class to `cout`:

```
    using namespace boost;                                                      
    using namespace log;                                                        
    using namespace expressions;                                                
    using namespace sinks;                                                      

    auto sink = make_shared<synchronous_sink<text_ostream_backend>>();          

    sink->set_formatter(Utility::GetLoggingFormat());                           

    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(                                         
        shared_ptr<std::ostream>(&std::cout, null_deleter()));                  
    sink->set_filter((                                                          
        has_attr(Utility::ClassTag) &&                                          
        Utility::ClassTag == "App::Trainer"));                                  
    boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
```

However, I have already added a sink (by calling `add_file_log` elsewhere) that dumps all log lines to a file. It uses the same `GetLoggingFormat()` formatter. In fact, the only reason I have that function is so that I don't have to repeat the formatter code.

Instead, I'd prefer to just "copy" the file sink (created elsewhere with `add_file_log`), change its output to `std::cout` and add the filter to it.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that cannot be done. Sinks cannot be copied, and in fact the sinks created by `add_file_log` are using not `text_ostream_backend` but `text_file_backend`; you cannot configure `text_file_backend` to output to `std::cout`.

Your best approach is to either use a function, like you already do, or cache the formatter in a [`formatter`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/basic_formatter.html) object and set it to both your sinks.